# How can I reshape this 2D array to a 4D array?

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, reshape

I have a 2D array of laminar flame speeds in the form of:

```
T1 P1 phi1 EGR1 S
T1 P2 phi1 EGR1 S
.
.
.
T1 P12 phi1 EGR1 S
T1 P13 phi1 EGR1 S
T1 P1 phi2 EGR1 S
T1 P2 phi2 EGR1 S
.
.
.
T1 P12 phi2 EGR1 S
T1 P13 phi2 EGR1 S
.
.
.
.
.
.
T28 P1 phi5 EGR1 S
T28 P2 phi5 EGR1 S
.
.
.
T28 P12 phi5 EGR1 S
T28 P13 phi5 EGR1 S
```

Where there are 28 different initial temperature (T1 - T28), 13 different initial pressures (P1 - P13), and 5 different fuel-air ratios (phi1 - phi5). EGR level doesn't change (`EGR1`), and then the resulting flame speed is listed as `S`.

So this is a 2D array of size (1820,5). I would like to convert it to a 4D array in MATLAB in the form of: A(5,5,13,28). So each page is 5 fuel-air ratios at a specific pressure and temperature, i.e., 5x5. The next page (3rd dimension), changes the pressure to `P2`, but keeps the temperature the same. Then finally, the 4th dimension increases the initial temperature.

I am familiar with the `reshape` and `permute` functions, but just can't seem to get it to what I want. Can anyone lend a hand?

Comment: Matlab's reshape will keep columns together while breaking up rows and you want the opposite. Try transposing your array (i.e. X' instead of X) and then reshaping. You may need to transpose each 5x5 'page' (as your refer t0 them) which can be done using 'permute' (i.e. permute(X_new,[2 1 3 4]).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should give you the result you want, assuming `data2D` is in the form you give in your example:

```
data4D = permute(reshape(data2D, [13 5 28 5]), [2 4 1 3]);
```

First, note that in the 2D data the second column (`P`) cycles most rapidly, followed by the third column (`phi`) then the first column (`T`). This is why I chose `[13 5 28 5]` in the [`reshape`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) step, which results in a 4D matrix where `P` varies across the first dimension, `phi` across the second, `T` across the third, and your row data across the fourth.

The [`permute`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) step then simply reorganizes the dimensions in the order `[2 4 1 3]`, such that `phi` varies across the first dimension, your row data across the second, `P` across the third, and `T` across the fourth.

Comment: Thank you for your help. That's exactly what I wanted. So it seems with your method the matrix didn't have to be transposed.

So in general, should I always reshape firstly according to the variable that cycles most rapidly, then then 2nd most rapid, etc? Previously, I always just guestimated until I got it.

Comment: @user3654549: It didn't have to be *initially* transposed, but the final `permute` step is basically a multidimensional transpose. I've found that reshaping based on cycle rate then permuting makes it much easier to understand, but there may be more efficient ways to organize steps for a given problem.